# Hadoop HADOOP_CLASSPATH issues

Tags: jar, hadoop, classpath

This question doesn't refer to distributing jars in the whole cluster for the workers to use them.

It refers to specifying a number of additional libraries on the client machine. To be more specific: I'm trying to run the following command in order to retrieve the contents of a SequenceFile:

```
   /path/to/hadoop/script fs -text /path/in/HDFS/to/my/file
```

It throws me this error: `text: java.io.IOException: WritableName can't load class: util.io.DoubleArrayWritable`

I have a writable class called DoubleArrayWritable. In fact , on another computer everything works well.

I tried to set the `HADOOP_CLASSPATH` to include the jar containing that class but with no results. Actually, when running:

```
   /path/to/hadoop/script classpath
```

The result doesn't contain the jar which I added to HADOOP_CLASSPATH.

The question is: how do you specify extra libraries when running hadoop (by extra meaning other libraries than the ones which the hadoop script includes automatically in the classpath)

Some more info which might help:

- I can't modify the hadoop.sh script (nor any associated scripts)
- I can't copy my library to the /lib directory under the hadoop installation directory
- In the hadoop-env.sh which is run from the hadoop.sh there is this line: `export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_HOME/lib` which probably explains why my HADOOP_CLASSPATH env var is ignored.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you are allowed to set `HADOOP_CLASSPATH` then

```
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=/path/to/jar/myjar.jar:$HADOOP_CLASSPATH; \
    hadoop fs -text /path/in/HDFS/to/my/file
```

will do the job. Since in your case this variable is *overridden* in `hadoop-env.sh` therefore, consider using the `-libjars` option instead:

```
hadoop fs -libjars /path/to/jar/myjar.jar -text /path/in/HDFS/to/my/file
```

Alternatively invoke `FsShell` manually:

```
java -cp $HADOOP_HOME/lib/*:/path/to/jar/myjar.jar:$CLASSPATH \
org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsShell -conf $HADOOP_HOME/conf/core-site.xml \
-text /path/in/HDFS/to/my/file
```

Comment: yes but the hadoop script does this: export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_HOME/lib. It rewrites my HADOOP_CLASSPATH

Comment: as I said, I don't want to set the "distributed" classpath. I just want to set the classpath on the client machine

Comment: @Razvan : Ok. Then you can invoke FsShell manually (see the example above).

Answer (score 4):

If someone wants to check hadoop classpath, enter `hadoop classpath` in terminal.
  To compile it, use this: `javac -cp $(hadoop classpath):path/to/jars/* java_file.java`

Answer (score 0):

Try to add your jar file in default CLASSPATH variable and also append HADOOP_CLASSPATH to it.
Then execute your command.

`export CLASSPATH=/your/jar/file/myjar.jar:$CLASSPATH:$HADOOP_CLASSPATH
/path/to/hadoop/script fs -text /path/in/HDFS/to/my/file`

Comment: the default classpath var is ignored by hadoop