# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/util/PlatformName

Tags: java, linux, hadoop, cloudera

I know there have been many posts regarding this exception, but I am not able to fix this issue. Classpath has to be edited I think to resolve it. 
I am trying to run a program called DistMap in hadoop infrastructure. This is the error I am getting.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.util.PlatformName
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: org.apache.hadoop.util.PlatformName.  Program will exit.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/fs/FsShell
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsShell
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsShell.  Program will exit.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/util/PlatformName
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.util.PlatformName
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: org.apache.hadoop.util.PlatformName.  Program will exit.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/fs/FsShell
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsShell
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsShell.  Program will exit.
Error could not create input directory /distmap_output_input folder on hdfs file system
```

which java says

```
/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_32/bin/java
```

echo $CLASSPATH gives a blank line

cat ~/.bash_profile says

```
cat ~/.bash_profile
# .bash_profile

# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
        . ~/.bashrc
fi

# User specific environment and startup programs

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin

export PATH
```

Update:

$HADOOP_HOME `/usr/lib/hadoop`

$HADOOP_CLASSPATH

`/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/hadoop-ant-2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.4.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop‌​-0.20-mapreduce/hadoop-ant.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/hadoop-examples-2.0‌​.0-mr1-cdh4.4.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/hadoop-examples.jar:/usr/lib/h‌​adoop-0.20-mapreduce/hadoop-core.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/hadoop-core-2‌​.0.0-mr1-cdh4.4.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/hadoop-test-2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.4‌​.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/hadoop-test.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/hadoop-tools-2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.4.0.jar:/usr/lib/hado‌​op-0.20-mapreduce/hadoop-tools.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/*jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-common.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-common-2.0.0-cdh4.4.0.jar`

The last 2 jar files have those classes PlatformName and FsShell. Still its not working.

Can anyone please help me fix this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Seems it can not locate `hadoop-core.jar`, just make sure the jar file is incluced in your `CLASSPATH`.

Comment: is that done like this? PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:/usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-core.jar

Comment: Do I have to change that PATH to $PATH:$usr/java/jdk1.6.0_32/bin?

Comment: No. It should be `CLASSPATH` not `PATH`. Should be something like CLASSPATH=.:/usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-core.jar. Or you can specify the CLASSPATH when you start your program.

Comment: ok export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$HOME/bin:/usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-core.jar ?

Comment: CLASSPATH=.:$CLASSPATH:/usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-core.jar.

Comment: that doesn't seem to work. I am still getting the same error..

Comment: echo $CLASSPATH /usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/hadoop-ant-2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.4.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop‌​-0.20-mapreduce/hadoop-ant.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/hadoop-examples-2.0‌​.0-mr1-cdh4.4.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/hadoop-examples.jar:/usr/lib/h‌​adoop-0.20-mapreduce/hadoop-core.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/hadoop-core-2‌​.0.0-mr1-cdh4.4.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/hadoop-test-2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.4‌​.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/hadoop-test.jar:

Comment: /usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/hadoop-tools-2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.4.0.jar:/usr/lib/hado‌​op-0.20-mapreduce/hadoop-tools.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/ I included all jars in my classpath. Still no luck.

Comment: IS there a hadoop-core jar in 2.2.0? I just download the last stable version from Apache and I cant find it. There is hadoop-mapreduce-client-core, but only hadoop-core I believe there is not. I'm also having the same exception and cant figure out why

Answer (score 18):

**hadoop-auth-2.2.0.jar** should be there for **hadoop2.2.0**

Add **hadoop auth jar** for your version

Answer (score 3):

If you are a maven user and faced this issue -

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
        <version>${hadoop.client.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
        <version>${hadoop.client.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

NOTE: `:hadoop-client:2.5.2` alone didn't bring in all the required hadoop dependencies. That is why I added `hadoop-common`, which brought all the required deps.

Answer (score 1):

In my particular case, I am using Maven, and although I had hadoop-auth in both the POM and the classpath, I was still getting this exception.

What finally fixed it for me was changing the scope for the dependency in the POM from "provided" to "compile".

Answer (score 0):

[Hadoop HADOOP_CLASSPATH issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12940239/hadoop-hadoop-classpath-issues)

This would be helpful.

Thanks & Regards,
Alok Thaker

Comment: I didn't quite understand as there are many hadoop folders with many jars. I am not understanding which one to set.