# NoClassDefFoundError caused by ClassNotFoundException in Hadoop on Hive Driver Connection line?

Tags: java, jdbc, hadoop, hive, classnotfoundexception

Typically I start by Googling for a solution, but this error does not seem to have occurred before.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/util/Shell
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf$ConfVars.findHadoopBinary(HiveConf.java:906)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf$ConfVars.<clinit>(HiveConf.java:237)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.isHttpTransportMode(HiveConnection.java:221)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.openTransport(HiveConnection.java:138)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.<init>(HiveConnection.java:123)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.connect(HiveDriver.java:105)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
    at com.merck.ghh.ingestion.HiveTableSetup.tableSetup(HiveTableSetup.java:31)
    at com.merck.ghh.ingestion.HiveTableSetup.main(HiveTableSetup.java:546)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 10 more
```

The following code causes this error, specifically on the Connection declaration line:

```
try {     
Class.forName(driverName);
     Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default", "hive", "");
     Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
} catch (ClassNotFoundException exception) {
      exception.printStackTrace();
}
```

Other [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18974098/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-hadoop-uti) seem to point to this being related to not including hadoop-core in the dependencies, but hadoop-core does not seem to exist in the Hadoop 2.X.  I am specifically working in Hadoop 2.1.0.2.0.5.0-67 with Hive 0.12.0.  Before this error I was having issues bc my Hive dependencies had gotten destroyed at some point, but I put those back in and this error happened next.  I'm wondering if it's not something as simple as forgetting a dependency, but I'm not finding which dependency I might be missing.

Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell
```

As you are using `Hadoop 2.X.` you need to download [hadoop-common-2.1.0-beta.jar](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-common/2.1.0-beta/hadoop-common-2.1.0-beta.jar) OR
 [hadoop-common-2.0.0-cdh4.4.0.jar](https://repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-common/2.0.0-cdh4.4.0/hadoop-common-2.0.0-cdh4.4.0.jar) and to class path to avoid `ClassNotFoundException`.

You are right earlier [hadoop-core-0.20.2-737.jar](https://repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/com/cloudera/hadoop/hadoop-core/0.20.2-737/hadoop-core-0.20.2-737.jar) was used.

For more visit [http://grepcode.com/](http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-common/2.1.0-beta/)

Comment: It was a simple issue! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try copying the JDBC connector jar into the $HIVE_HOME/lib/ folder. I faced a similar issue and copying the jar file worked for me.

Comment: I already have this file linked from it's install directory to the hive/lib directory.  Thank you very much for the input though.