# `hadoop dfs` command java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/fs/FsShell

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, hadoop2, microsoft-distributed-file-system

I am trying to run `hadoop dfs` command on `cygwin` with `Hadoop - 2.6.3`

I am running following command

`/cygdrive/c/hadoop-2.6.4/bin/hadoop dfs -put word1 words/` which eventually throws an error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/fs/FsShell
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsShell
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsShell.  Program will exit.
Exception in thread "main"
```

I have setup paths correctly

```
  $ echo $JAVA_HOME
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_31
```

and

```
$ echo $HADOOP_HOME
/cygdrive/c/hadoop-2.6.4/
```

Can anyone help me here?

I also tried running `hadoop-env.sh` file from `$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop` but in vain

Comment: @Seth: I haven't written any java code yet. This is the command fired from `hadoop` `bin` folder. It's `hadoop` command.

Comment: @Seth: Any idea which dependency it could be?

Comment: I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18974098/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-hadoop-uti maybe it holds the key?

Comment: Not sure why but it worked in ubuntu. The same set of things I have done for ubuntu environment. I am keeping this question open so anyone having answer may post it below.