# error in starting hbase with Hadoop-2.2.0

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

I have installed and configured Hbase-0.94.14 with hadoop-2.2.0. I'm getting following error while starting HBase.

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.util.PlatformName
```

I have not found any reasonable material that explains me, why is this  happening. I believe I'm missing some .jar file, but don't know which one. there is a huge change in Hadoop structure. With hadoop-1.x only one hadoop-core.x.jar file was enough. But in hadoop.2.x I have not found hadoop-core jar.
If any body knows why it is happening, please help me.

NOTE: I'm having this error while starting HBase. Hadoop is running fine.

Answer (score 0):

That's the problem about your hadoop classpath and you can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12940239/hadoop-hadoop-classpath-issues) if it helps. Obviously it can't find the class and its jar file. I'm not sure about the newest hadoop.2.x but setting the HADOOP_CLASSPATH may help you find the jars.